# I use curl to submit sitemap but doesnt get reflection in webportal

Tags: seo, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

this is TWO things confused me that how should I submit my sitemap.

**First.**
It is understood that a sitemap can be submitted with cURL. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en

However, every time the sitemap submission doesnt reflect in the web portal. The timestamp in the webportal only shows the time I submit the sitemap in through the webportal.

Why they are different? Is submitting via curl working?

**Second**
I found that google only crawl my website just after the first time I submit the sitemap. I update my site and sitemap regularly, and hoping google can crawl my site. However, it seems that google never come back.

What is wrong with these?

If you can see the picture, you will see there several peaks just after I submit the sitemap through Search Console. If you leave it alone, then it turns to be flat.

[image]

Comment: When you say "web portal" do you mean "Google Search Console"?

Comment: It would be very unusual for Googlebot to never re-crawl the pages on your site.   Are you sure you aren't getting any additional crawling from Googlebot?    Googlebot should be coming back to re-crawl pages at least every couple months once it first finds them, regardless of what you do with sitemaps.

Comment: yes, the web portal means google search console.

I go the the old version of Search Console, where crawler stats can be available there. The Pages crawled per day tends to be flat.  It seems that the times of crawling went up only if I submit the sitemap again. Otherwise, it never come back.